# How to manage cache of node js server?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to ask about NodeJS, especially the Express framework. I and the team just developed 
a mobile application using NodeJS express as a link to the database (NodeJS / Express working in a background).

a few days ago we encountered a problem where our server cache(RAM using) was full and we 
restarted the node and the server cache returned to normal. 
Now what we are doing is restarting the node every day.

Can there be a configuration 
error on the server or is there a problem with the code on our node that causes the cache to be full?

Comment: What server are you using ?

Comment: What cache are you using? Are you using something like memcache?

Comment: im not sure, i think im not using memcahce, but what i mean that our node js consume much RAM almost 400MB, our server specification 1 core and 1 GB RAM, and we are using vestacp for control panel

Comment: you can use redis to manage cache on node js it is fast and good for these tasks

Comment: You did not take into consideration the management of available memory. `memcached`, when there is a lack of a dedicated memory pool - it removes the least used elements. `redis` also remove, but it have copy on disk.